# DM friends with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote this code that by all means should work. If you can't help me fix it then could someone help me write in in the python discum library?:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for user in bot.user.friends:
        message = "This Message is sent via DM"
        await bot.send_message(user, message)

bot.run("")
```

and it throws up this eror even though the token is valid.:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\HWMonitor\squirm\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    bot.run("ODI5Mzc2MDY2Nzk0ODE1NDk4.YNYJEQ.crJ2GzQZxRkCXy6fsd1zS8lxZCE")
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\ArtyF\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001C7D4077940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Bots do not have an attribute to friends, this would only work for selfbots, which are against [discord TOS](https://discord.com/terms). Also, `bot.send_message` has also been deprecated, you'll need to use `user.send(message)` instead (to send dms in general)

Comment: This is a test and not going to be actually used. Thanks for deprecation notice tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think To DM Users You Have To Use The User Object!

Example

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

Token = "Token Here"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for user in bot.user.friends:
        message = "This Message is sent via DM"
        await user.send(message)

bot.run(Token)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you get the error `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`. You need to pass an API key to get authenticated.

Comment: Uh where do I put the api key and what is an api key? @Louis-Justin Tallot

Comment: You can get an api key from the developer's portal: https://discord.com/developers/applications/{your bot id}/oauth2